FIR filter to perform Hilbert transform
i want to design a fir filter that perform Hilbert transform, below is my code, but after i design and apply to a 1d signal, I notice that the filter is not responding as the ideal Hilbert transform, i need help please.
here is my code:
len = 31;
h = firpm(len-1, [0.005 0.995], [1 1], 'hilbert'); h = h(:);
d = zeros(len,1); d((len+1)/2) = 1;

% Test the filter with a simulated signal
t = 0:0.01:10;  % Time vector
f = 1;          % Frequency of the sinusoid
samples = sin(2*pi*f*t);  % Sinusoidal signal

% Apply the Hilbert transform to the signal
hilbert_signal = conv(samples, h, "same");
% Normalize amplitude of the Hilbert transformed signal
hilbert_Nsignal = hilbert_signal / max(abs(hilbert_signal)) * max(abs(samples));

% Plot the Original Signal Hilbert transformed signals
figure();
g = imag(hilbert(samples));
figure()
plot(t,samples);
hold on
plot (t,g);

% Plot the original and Hilbert transformed signals
figure;
plot(t, samples);
hold on;
plot(t,g);
plot(t, hilbert_Nsignal);%(numtaps:end-numtaps+1));
title('Original Signal and Hilbert Transform');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('Original Signal', 'Hilbert Transform', 'filter');
grid on;

% Plot the Hilbert inbuild & Hilbert transformed signals
figure;
plot(t,g, t,hilbert_Nsignal)
legend('Hilbert Transform (Ideal)', 'Filtered Signal');




It's not a new question.  If you want half-band symmetry (that forces every even-indexed tap to be zero) than simply windowing the ideal with a good window sorta does the trick.  Remember that this all needs to be delayed by $M$ samples and also the in-phase signal by the same amount.

The problem that is causing the main discrepancy (that is, at the edges) is that the hilbert() function does the convolution as discrete Fourier transform domain multiplication (see Matlab hilbert documentation algorithm section), which actually is circular convolution, whereas the conv() function does time domain convolution.
A smaller problem, but one that must be acknowledged, is that your FIR Hilbert transformer only provides an approximation of the Hilbert transform, as mentioned in the Matlab firpm documentation, which you'll have to accept to a degree as the ideal Hilbert transformer can't be realised (Feldman, 2011).
To solve the main discrepancy, you need to change what you pass to the conv function so that what it returns contains the circular convolution result. You can do this by extending your signal through repeating it to the extent necessary based on the filter length. Here is an example of Matlab code that does this, which you can use to replace your line of code that calls the conv function:
extended_samples = samples(1+mod(1-ceil(length(h)/2):length(samples)-1+floor(length(h)/2),length(samples)));
hilbert_signal = conv(extended_samples, h, "valid");

When I made this change to your code, this is the new figure I got, which is a significant improvement but, as mentioned, you can still see the small effects of the FIR Hilbert transformer only being an approximation of the Hilbert transform when you zoom in:


Thank you Stephen, please how can I connect with you - need to discuss more

@user72940, at present your reputation is insufficient for the system to allow you to participate in chat rooms. I suggest posting your question(s) to the Signal Processing Stack Exchange to have the best chance of getting a good answer based on the collective knowledge of contributors.

Basically, I want to use it as a building for real time processing (video), and I need to know if the filter is design well for the performance.

@user72940, I have no experience with video processing, and this appears outside the scope of the original question. I suggest posting a separate question and/or researching it using https://scholar.google.com/, etc, or simply testing it to see if it meets you application needs.

I consider using the convolution 'same' which I tried to do zero padding, but still no solution.

It appears you don't understand the conv function shape argument. As a suggestion, compare the full shape to the same and valid shapes so you can see how they how they are related. Once you understand that, along with understanding circular convolution, you'll be able to manipilate it as you need.
